# Trigger PHP script after submit button - using react js

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I worked on a tool that was in HTML and used JQuery for AJAX calls to run PHP scripts. But now the requirement is to use React JS and I am new to it. I dint find good document to see how to trigger PHP scripts using React JS. 
Is there any link or document which has examples of these? any help is highly appreciated.

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id = "button" value="submit"  >Submit</button>
  $('#button').click(function () { ..... }

 In react : 
 <button type="button"> <span> Submit </span>
```

Comment: By the way, your button tag doesn't end, which can cause issues. You are only closing the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen either on button click, or form submit... In example, event handler listens on form submit. 
Event handler prevents form from being sent. Instead, you should process data and send them to your PHP script (via Fetch API, AJAX call, ...)

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Handle it on your own');
},

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/34020/

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.
Cant we send values of inputs - i face an error  $ is undefined 
var a = parseInt($('#demo1').val());
        var b = parseInt($('#demo2').val());
        var sum = a + b;
        alert(sum);

Comment: you're doing it wrong. With React in use, you don't access DOM at all (okay, only in rare edge cases). What does your form look like? Show us the structure

Comment: Just to play with, I tried two input tags as numbers and I am trying to populate their sum as alert when i click the submit button. I am confused how is it done otherwise

Comment: I got the flow of your program and its returning as JSON. I was trying to pass in numbers and do an addition. But its going blank!